# Parse app for clients

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I have made a Parse-based app that allows the user to send a push notification to everyone who downloads the app.  It's a kind of quick public address system for a congregation, school, club, etc.

Other leaders have expressed an interest in my app for their communities.  But these people are not tech-savvy and have no interest in becoming Apple developers for $100 a year, so building custom apps for them is not an option. Even if I did it for them, I would be concerned that they would mess something up that would require a lot of time on my part to repair. They just want to use the app for their communities.

My question:  Could I make custom apps for these groups, keep them on my iTunesConnect account, and simply make a new Parse account for each app?  That way, the group leaders would only need to know how to log into Parse and send a push notification on the Parse website.

Thank you,

Eli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could. It could be done with a single app that everyone downloads and then configures to connect it to their specific parse app.

It's possible that you could write the app so it doesn't know the parse account details and they need to be entered on the device. It's also possible that you could supply that detail with an invite e-mail that opens the app and has the details in the URL query.